# Java DCEVM - Getting "Could not get dceverion of D:\Java8" for Java 1.8.0.202 version

Tags: java, java-8, hotswap, dcevm, hotswapagent

Java version: `1.8.0_202 JDK`
and **DCEVM** jar `[DCEVM-8u181-installer.jar][1]`

After executing above jar and on click of button `Replace by DCEVM` and `Install DCEVM as altjvm` in UI popup.

I am getting message **`Could not get dceversion of D:\Java8`** and the DCEVM, HotSwap is not working.

Is there any way to resolve this or any alternate compatible dcevm jar/solution/workaround to support **Java 1.8.0.202** or **later version**.

Also open for any other alternate opensource library to achieve the hotswapping in java 8.

Thanks in advance.

[image: Could not get dceversion]

Comment: Maybe try the OpenJDK one with a matching version of Dcevm.

Comment: Did you solve it? I encounter the same problem

Comment: I have the same issue

Comment: No was not able to resolve the issue, meanwhile I switched to use JRebel hot reload (Licensed).